# How Get Value for General Properties Html.DisplayFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

how implement This Code in mvc core
when Generate Model In Mvc Core

```
@foreach (var itemRow in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var itemValue in itemRow.GetType().GetProperties())
                        {
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => itemValue)
                                
              //@itemRow.GetType().GetProperty(itemValue.Name).GetValue(itemRow, null)
                            </td>
                        }
                       
                    </tr>
                }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
                <tr>
                    
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>            
                 </tr>
        }
```